# What does opencv `mean` function do when passing a mask of zeros?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, c++

**INTRO**

I am looking at [this project](https://github.com/eladj/detectParking/tree/master/cpp) to implement some changes.

The project is written in C++ using openCV library. Its goal is to detect cars in parking area to calculate the number of free spots. It does this in real-time (takes the input of a camera and processes it frame by frame).

The detection is performed on areas of the image that are rectangles whose vertices are loaded from a file. For each park (i.e. rectangle) to be monitored there is an instance of the class `Parking` defined in the files `Parking.***` and all of them are collected in a vector (named `parking_data` in the following lines of code)

**CODE**

As far as I understood the processing starts on line 83 of the file `main.cpp`. The interesting lines are these:

```
cv::cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::GaussianBlur(frame_gray, frame_blur, blur_kernel, 3, 3);
//...
for (Parking& park : parking_data)
{
  // Check if parking is occupied
  roi = frame_blur(park.getBoundingRect());
  cv::Laplacian(roi, laplacian, CV_64F);                                
  delta = cv::mean(cv::abs(laplacian), park.getMask());
  park.setStatus( delta[0] < atof(ConfigLoad::options["PARK_LAPLACIAN_TH"].c_str()) );
```

`cvtColor` converts the frame to grayscale then a gaussian blurring filter is applied. Then it iterates to the elements of the vector `parking_data` containing the instances of the class `Parking` which represent the area in the image corresponding to the parking spots.

`getBoundingRect` should return the vertices of the rectangle so to get a subimage of the blurred frame. Then a Laplacian filter is applied.

**QUESTION**

The line I do not understand is `delta = cv::mean(cv::abs(laplacian), park.getMask());`.

I understand it is calcualating a mean of the absolute value of the laplacian subimage. The mask is defined only in line 49 and used in the followings of the file `Parking.cpp` as

```
mask = cv::Mat::zeros(bounding_rect.size(), CV_8UC1);
for (cv::Point p : contours_points.at(0))
{
  polygon_points_in_bounding_rect.push_back(cv::Point(p.x - bounding_rect.x, p.y - bounding_rect.y));
}
vector<vector<cv::Point>> contours;
contours.push_back(polygon_points_in_bounding_rect);        
cv::drawContours(mask, contours, -1, cv::Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);
```

so it is a matrix of 0s. 
Then the value is compared to a given threshold.

OpenCV on the function says about the `mean` function.

`When all the mask elements are 0's, the functions return Scalar::all(0)`

So what is the `mean` function calculating when passing a mask of zeros?

Answer (score 1):

The function `cv:mean` calculates the mean value of the marked out area in the `InputArray` as you said. So the function looks at the area which is filled with the mask (zeros) and calculates the mean value of the `InputArray` which is not filled with zeros.

I know the code you are showing here. I don't understand why the function `cv:Laplacian` is used here because in my opinion this is not relevant in this case. Maybe someone else knows why he used the Laplacian array instead of using the `blured_gray` array.

I hope I could help you.